# Pusher for Windows Phone failing to disconnect

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, deadlock, pusher

I have encountered a problem with pusherClient.wp8 package I installed from Nuget. Every time the app is sent to the background, I disconnect from pusher and unsubscribe from the channel. when I resume the app, the code hang when connection is re-established with pusher.

I have tried to reset the pusher object, reset the channel, create a new instance of pusher, and still nothing works, it seems there is a problem with the package, or rather the websocket disconnect method is failing to disconnect from pusher, however, when I close the app, everything get reseted. but this does not help me in instances when a user open a photopicker from my app.

Does anyone has a suggestion or know of another pusherclient I can use for windows phone 8. I have been struggling with this problem for weeks now.
Here is the github link of the package I used: https://github.com/bszypelow/PusherClient.WP8/blob/master/PusherClient.WP8

Thank you

```
public ConnectionState Connect()
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () => await pusher.ConnectAsync()); ;
    try
    {
        task.Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Exception " + ex.Message + " at " + ex.Source + "Inner exception " + ex.InnerException + " additional data " + ex.Data);
    }
    return task.Result;
}
```

Comment: Which method it hanging? is it Subscribe or SubscribeToChannel?

Comment: the method that is hanging is ConnectAsync()

Comment: Well, that's the same problem as I described.

Comment: Could you post the code where you call this method?

Comment: I will edit the post to insert the code now

Comment: Yep, that's a typical code for a deadlock. So check out my answer and modify the source code of the Pusher. (It's small enough to to that in a reasonable time).  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I ll try what you have suggested and try to get in touch with the person who created the pusher package or download it and try make changes to it. I will definitely let you know if that works

Comment: you can fork it on github and fix it. You also can just add it's source code to your project, or you can create your own NuGet package.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source code I have a guess:

All the async methods never use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` which could be a [reason for the dead lock.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)
Especially if you call [it from the UI thread](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx) using the [.Wait()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.wait(v=vs.110).aspx) or [.Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx). From event for example.

I suggest you to update the code (it's MIT license, you can do that):

```
public Task<Channel> Subscribe(string channelName)
{
    if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Connected)
        throw new PusherException("You must wait for Pusher to connect before you can subscribe to a channel", ErrorCodes.NotConnected);

    if (Channels.ContainsKey(channelName))
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Channels[channelName]);
    }

    // If private or presence channel, check that auth endpoint has been set
    var chanType = ChannelTypes.Public;

    if (channelName.ToLower().StartsWith("private-"))
        chanType = ChannelTypes.Private;
    else if (channelName.ToLower().StartsWith("presence-"))
        chanType = ChannelTypes.Presence;

    return SubscribeToChannel(chanType, channelName); //await is not needed here
}

private async Task<Channel> SubscribeToChannel(ChannelTypes type, string channelName)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case ChannelTypes.Public:
            Channels.Add(channelName, new Channel(channelName, this));
            break;
        case ChannelTypes.Private:
            AuthEndpointCheck();
            Channels.Add(channelName, new PrivateChannel(channelName, this));
            break;
        case ChannelTypes.Presence:
            AuthEndpointCheck();
            Channels.Add(channelName, new PresenceChannel(channelName, this));
            break;
    }

    if (type == ChannelTypes.Presence || type == ChannelTypes.Private)
    {
        string jsonAuth = await _options.Authorizer.Authorize(channelName, _connection.SocketID)
         .ConfigureAwait(false); //do not capture the context!!

        var template = new { auth = String.Empty, channel_data = String.Empty };
        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(jsonAuth, template);

        _connection.Send(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { @event = Constants.CHANNEL_SUBSCRIBE, data = new { channel = channelName, auth = message.auth, channel_data = message.channel_data } }));
    }
    else
    {
        // No need for auth details. Just send subscribe event
        _connection.Send(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { @event = Constants.CHANNEL_SUBSCRIBE, data = new { channel = channelName } }));
    }

    return Channels[channelName];
}
```

You can checkout the source code, than if you don't use it now you can install trial version of [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and [this plug-in](https://resharper-plugins.jetbrains.com/packages/ConfigureAwaitChecker.v9/). They will help you to find all the lines where [.ConfigureAwait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait(v=vs.110).aspx) is missing.